# SwiftUI AppDelegate: Show sheet when notification is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Problem**
I want to show a sheet or navigate to a specific view with SwiftUI when the user presses on a notification.

I'm seeking advice on what the best approach would be to solve this problem in a SwiftUI app.

---

Inside my AppDelegate I currently have:

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

  
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    
    // Here I want to implement a function, that opens a sheet or navigates to a specific view //
    print("User tapped notification")

  
    completionHandler()
      
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?

**Overview of structure of the app**

```
@main
struct jsonlistingApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
    }

}
```

```
struct MainView: View {

 var body: some View {
        
                TabView {

                    PostList()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Søg", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                        }
                    FavoritesView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Favoritter", systemImage: "heart")
                        }
                    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                        BoligAgentView()
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Boligagent", systemImage: "bell")
                            }
                            .badge(UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)
                    }
                    else {
                        BoligAgentView()
                            .tabItem {
                                Label("Boligagent", systemImage: "bell")
                            }
                    }
                    Settings()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Profil", systemImage: "person")
                        }
                
            }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: on receiving your notification you can set some @ObservedObject property and based on this value programmatically select the respective TabView.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65961637/swiftui-notification-click-go-to-a-specific-view

Comment: `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` is not glued to `AppDelegate`. Create a independent class and adopt `ObservableObject`